# DiffUtil clashes with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when updating the recyclerview adapter list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin-coroutines, android-diffutils

I'm trying to update `ViewPager2` adapter with a new list of items using `DiffUtil` but it keeps clashing now and then.

from the Fragment

```
private suspend fun updateMap(items: List<Item>) {
       
        briefAdapter.submitList(items)
        
    }
```

Adapter

```
 private var items = ArrayList<Item>()

    
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    suspend fun submitList(newItems: List<Item>) {
        val diff = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            val diffCallBack = BriefDiffCallBack(items, newItems)
            val diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffCallBack)
            diffResult
        }
        items.clear()
        items.addAll(newItems)
        diff.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }
```

DiffCallBack implementation

```
class BriefDiffCallBack(
    private val oldList: List<Item>,
    private val newList: List<Item>
) : DiffUtil.Callback() {


    override fun getOldListSize(): Int {
        return oldList.size
    }

    override fun getNewListSize(): Int {
        return newList.size
    }

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        return try {
            val old = oldList[oldItemPosition]
            val new = newList[newItemPosition]
            
            old.id == new.id 
            
        } catch (exc: Exception) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            false
        }
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        return try {
            val old = oldList[oldItemPosition]
            val new = newList[newItemPosition]

            return old == new
           
        } catch (exc: Exception) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            false
        }
    }
}
```

Clash

```
androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil$DiffResult.findMatchingAddition
DiffUtil.java, line 744
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=45; index=45
```

stacktrace

```
androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil$DiffResult.findMatchingAddition DiffUtil.java:744
androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil$DiffResult.findMoveMatches DiffUtil.java:723
androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil$DiffResult.findMatchingItems DiffUtil.java:712
androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil$DiffResult.<init> DiffUtil.java:675
androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil.calculateDiff DiffUtil.java:178
androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil.calculateDiff DiffUtil.java:106
ListingBriefAdapter$submitList$diff$1.invokeSuspend BriefAdapter.kt:46
kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith ContinuationImpl.kt:33
kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run DispatchedTask.kt:106
kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely CoroutineScheduler.kt:571
kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask CoroutineScheduler.kt:750
kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker CoroutineScheduler.kt:678
kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run CoroutineScheduler.kt:665
```

Comment: Found any solution?

Comment: @AsthaGarg the only work round i found is creating a copy of the old listings to use it to calculate the difference.                                                                            `val diffCallBack = BriefDiffCallBack(ArrayList(listings), newListings)
`

Comment: @AsthaGarg see the answer  below

Answer (score 1):

Updating the adapter's arraylist while accessing the arraylist items at the same time was the root cause of `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` being thrown by the DiffUtil library. To avoid this and still maintain a smooth update of the UI, i made a copy of the underlying adapter's list and used it to calculate the difference instead of using the adapter's list directly (`BriefDiffCallBack(ArrayList(items), newItems)`). This ensured that the user will continue interacting with the old arraylist untill the difference in the two lists has being calculated and update is available.

**Adapter class**

```
private var items = ArrayList<Item>()


override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return items.size
}

suspend fun submitList(newItems: List<Item>) {
    val diff = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        val diffCallBack = BriefDiffCallBack(ArrayList(items), newItems)
        val diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffCallBack)
        diffResult
    }
    items.clear()
    items.addAll(newItems)
    diff.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
}
```

Comment: How is it helping you? I mean can you briefly explain your solution

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the same solution now, hoping to not see same crash on Playstore